# Generate a probability distribution from a histogram with two peaks

Tags: matlab, histogram

[image]I have a histogram with two peaks and I want to generate the corresponding probability distribution. I have used the following MATLAB code:

```
A=mydata;
M1=max(A);
M2=min(A);
I=(0:100).*(M1-M2)./100+M2;
[n,x]=hist(A,I);
bar(x,n/(1000*0.352))
```

I found this code frequently to explain how we can find a prob distribution for a histogram of random numbers normally distributed but I don't know whether if this true for a histogram with two peaks and generate a normalised probability distribution.

Comment: Regardless of the number of modes, normalizing a histogram is one way to generate an approximate probability density for your data. Can you be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Can you show us the histogram, and tell us more about how the data was generated? This probably belongs in stats.se...

Comment: I second this comment this question belongs in http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try using this FileExchange submission - [ALLFITDIST](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34943).

Not sure it can fit two peaks. But since they are quite far from each other, you can try to fit by range and then sum them together.